# Assigning sublist to variable if there is more than one arguement

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

So there's this project I'm working on for school and I can't figure out how to make this code work. If I input two words it works fine but if I only input one then it returns the error:

```
List index out of range.
```

I need it to assign the variable "`modifier`" if there are two words but ignore it if there is only one.

Any ideas?

```
commandinp = [input("ROOT:/" + directory + "> ")]
commandfull = [x.strip().split(' ') for x in commandinp]
for sublist in commandfull:
    command = sublist[0]
    size = len(commandfull) 
    if size > 0:
        modifier = sublist[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're looping here. If you need `modifier` to optionally have a value, use `partition`:

```
commands = input("ROOT:/" + directory + "> ").strip()
command, _, modifier = commands.partition(' ')
print(command, modifier)
```

partitioning with `' '` will partition the string in three parts; the first part is the value before the first space (`command`) the second the partitioning element (we use `_` here to dump it) and the third is the rest of the value following the space (`modifier`).

The following:

```
command, _, modifier = commands.partition(' ')
```

simply assigns the values partition to their corresponding names by unpacking.

With `sudo -s` and `sudo` the following values are attained:

```
ROOT:/dir/> sudo
>>> command
'sudo'
>>> modifier
''
```

and:

```
ROOT:/jim/> sudo -s    
>>> modifier
'-s'
>>> command
'sudo'
```

and so on.

As you noticed, I trimmed your original snippet down a bit; the brackets around `input` are because you're doing an `in` afterwards, from what I guess. You really don't need to do that since `split` will return a list for you.

The `for` loop seems like a bad idea too, you don't really need to do something with every value, you need to check it's size and assign appropriately. For that an `if` would do (even though `partition` saves us from that.)

If you *definitely don't want `modified` defined* if there's nothing for it you should use an `if` but, I think, assigning an empty string (that evaluates to `False` on `if` checks) is probably better than conditionally defining it.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out, appreciate the help:)

Comment: You're welcome @ElliotKempson. If this helped solve your question you could upvote and mark it as accepted for any other people who bump into it to see :-)